# Problem using greek symbols in pyplot in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a data from simulation from an .xvg file using python. I need to use greek symbols in my legend but I am unable to get them. This is my script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
count = np.genfromtxt('secondary_count.xvg',dtype=float,comments='#',skip_header=32)
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
time = count[:,0]
coil = count[:,1]
bsheet = count[:,2]
bridge = count[:,3]
bend = count[:,4]
turn = count[:,5]
a_helix = count[:,6]
helix_3 = count[:,7]
plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.13,0.13,0.80,0.80])
ax.plot(time,coil,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'violet',label = 'Coil')
ax.plot(time,bsheet,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'indigo',label = '$ \beta sheet$')
ax.plot(time,bridge,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'blue',label = '$ \beta bridge$')
ax.plot(time,bend,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'green',label = 'Bend')
ax.plot(time,turn,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'yellow',label = 'Turn')
ax.plot(time,a_helix,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'orange',label = '$ \alpha helix$')
ax.plot(time,helix_3,'d',linestyle = '-',linewidth = 2,color = 'red',label = '3-helix')
plt.legend(fontsize = 14,frameon = True)
plt.show()
```

I have tried using usetex = True option but it still doesn't work. I have tried installing **cm-super, dvipng, texlive-fonts-recommended and texlive-latex-extra**.Nothing works. This is the error that I am getting.

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$ \\x08eta -sheet$'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

(/home/chemical/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/a3495e870c3cb3da380651e9f4e7bb26.te
x
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 7 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/cm-super/type1ec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(./a3495e870c3cb3da380651e9f4e7bb26.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.19 {\sffamily $ ^^H
                     eta -sheet$}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on a3495e870c3cb3da380651e9f4e7bb26.log.
```

Comment: please go through this [link](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html)